# 400 Bad Request in HTTP/1.1 but not in HTTP/1.0

Tags: python, http, http-headers, httprequest

I'm trying to send a `HEAD` request to this url :

http://ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in/releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso

and get the size of the file. My current head request looks like this :

```
head_request = "HEAD " + file_path + " HTTP/1.0%s" % ('\r\n\r\n')
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).send(head_request)
```

where `file_path` is `"/releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"`. This works perfectly but when I replace `1.0` by `1.1`, I get a `400 HTTP Bad Request`.

```
head_request = "HEAD " + file_path + " HTTP/1.1%s" % ('\r\n\r\n')
```

Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTTP/1.1 you must provide the `Host:` header.

Demonstration using `netcat` (`nc`) utility:

```
$ nc ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in 80 <<END
HEAD /releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso HTTP/1.0

END
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 07:25:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 21:44:24 GMT
ETag: "5ca30000-5489895805e00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1554186240
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-iso9660-image

$ nc ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in 80 <<END
HEAD /releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1

END

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 07:25:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

$ nc ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in 80 <<END
HEAD /releases/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1
Host: ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in

END

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 07:27:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 21:44:24 GMT
ETag: "5ca30000-5489895805e00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1554186240
Content-Type: application/x-iso9660-image
```